# How To Keep Alive Spring Webflux WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux

I was working on spring web-flux reactive WebSocket , so I was trying to emulate a bidirectional text communication channel by which both I can send and well as receive message , I was successfully able to run a WebSocket server

```
public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession webSocketSession) {
     webSocketSession.receive().map(msg -> msg.getPayloadAsText())
        .doOnNext(ReactiveWebSocketHandler::processMessage).then();

    Flux<WebSocketMessage> hello = Flux.just(webSocketSession.textMessage("hello"));
    return webSocketSession.send(hello);
  }
```

when I start the application and hit the endpoint it replies with a message , but when I try to send a message handler is not receiving , how to establish a keep-alive bi directional WebSocket connection

Answer (score 0):

```
webSocketSession.receive().map(msg -> msg.getPayloadAsText())
        .doOnNext(ReactiveWebSocketHandler::processMessage).then();
```

this is a publisher and you're not subscribing to it, so the data will not flow in doOnNext. Add subsribe method to it and it you will receive the message.
The reason why you get a replied message is because you are returning a publisher and netty server subscribe to that Mono.